# Android video recording 2160p

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to record maximum quality video. And for my device (LG G Flex 2) it's 3840x2160. This resolution provides stock camera. Besides camera parameters info tells, that it's possible video-size for 3rd party apps.

If I try to use profiles:

```
CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_2160P)
```

It returns false. There is no such profile.

I also tried this:

```
CamcorderProfile prof = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P);
prof.videoFrameHeight = 2160;
prof.videoFrameWidth = 3840;
mMediaRecorder.setProfile(prof);
```

But it also doesn't work.

And finally:

```
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(3840, 2160);
```

Doesn't work too.

The error is

```
03-20 01:53:02.800: E/MediaRecorder(17459): start failed: -19
```

Is there any other ways to record video?
I am using camera1 api and `camera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes()` contains 3840x2160

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.  Specify an error message or describe the bad behavior instead.

Comment: Also just because the "stock camera app" - which has been modified by the manufacturer can do it doesn't mean third party apps can. Related post on Camera2 API support: http://spectrastudy.com/camera2-api-on-mwc-2015-devices/

Comment: I updated my question.
@MorrisonChang thank you for article, it's pretty informative. And what about LG G Flex 2 - It supports FULL camera2 api. But I'm using camera1 api for video recording.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using:

```
mediarecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
```

It will automatically record the video with the highest available resolution supported by the device. You don't need to specify any other parameters for this it will use the best available with that device.

If you need the working code to record videos I can provide that too.

Comment: Might as well include it.

Comment: @kamal2305 thank you! But this setting records 1080p video on my device.

Comment: @Maxim: Which device your using to record videos? This could be the highest supported resolution on your device.

Comment: @kamal2305: LG G Flex 2. As I mentioned it in question - camera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes() contains 3840x2160

Answer (score 0):

The method getSupportedVideoSizes() refers to the Android SDK. So it is returning a predefined list of supported video sizes under the corresponding SDK version. But the actual ones differ from device to device.

Quality level corresponding to the highest available resolution:

```
camProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
```

Quality level corresponding to the lowest available resolution:

```
camProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
```

Comment: I know it. I want to know if there is any other way to define settings for media recorder. For example: some devices camera support 1080p video recording, but maximum available profile is 720p. And we can use 720p profile, set width and height for 1080p and record video in 1080p. May be there is other hacks?

Answer (score 0):

As a hack can be used the following way to record 4K video:

```
// Get maximum available quality. And set width and height manually.
// To make new size have effect, we need also increase encoding bit rate.
CamcorderProfile prof = CamcorderProfile.get(CameraController.getCameraIndex(), CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
prof.videoFrameWidth = 3840;
prof.videoFrameHeight = 2160;
prof.videoBitRate = (int)(prof.videoBitRate*2.8);
mMediaRecorder.setProfile(prof);
```